# How to populate the next element of a given class with html content?

Tags: jquery-selectors

I'm trying to set up a set of links so that when one is clicked, the next div with the class "detailcontainer" is populated with some html. There is one `<div class="detailcontainer">` after every 3 links. So far, the jQuery I have looks like this. Obviously, as it is, the html is injected into every `<div class="detailcontainer">`. How can I refine this so that the content is only loaded into the next one??

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(jQuery) {
jQuery("a.click").click(function(){
jQuery(".detailcontainer").html("<p>content goes here.</p>");
return false;
});
});
</script>
```

My html structure is as follows...

```
<div class="set">
<div><a href="#" class="click">link</a></div>
<div><a href="#" class="click">link</a></div>
<div><a href="#" class="click">link</a></div>
</div>
<div class="detailcontainer"></div>
<div class="set">
<div><a href="#" class="click">link</a></div>
<div><a href="#" class="click">link</a></div>
<div><a href="#" class="click">link</a></div>
</div>
<div class="detailcontainer"></div>
etc. etc.
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An option is as follows:

Identify each detailcontainer div with a unique id and use that id as the classname of related anchors. In JS use the clicked classname to update the respective container.

```
<div class="set">
<div><a href="#" class="click1">link</a></div>
<div><a href="#" class="click1">link</a></div>
<div><a href="#" class="click1">link</a></div>
</div>
<div id="click1" class="detailcontainer"></div>
<div class="set">
<div><a href="#" class="click2">link</a></div>
<div><a href="#" class="click2">link</a></div>
<div><a href="#" class="click2">link</a></div>
</div>
<div id="click2" class="detailcontainer"></div>
```

Here is the updated JS code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(jQuery) {
       jQuery("a").click(function(){
       var divid = this.className;
       jQuery("#"+divid).html("<p>content goes here.</p>");
       return false;
       });
   });
```

Comment: Quality!!I was generating the elements using php, so there was a bit of a change to be made to my loop, but the different perspective helped me to get it all working.
Thanks a million!